# Connect direct line speech to skype call

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, skype, bot-framework-composer

I have build a bot using Microsoft bot framework (using the composer). And connected it to Direct Line Speech channel. I want to forward a skype call to the direct line service so that it can reply to the conversation on the other side. Is it possible using azure?

Answer (score 0):

voice enablement of Bots inside skype/Teams isn’t possible today, we can do this outside of Teams (WebChat, on-device apps with wake word detection) however unless WebChat is an option.

Async audio messages are not supported by bots at the moment; One idea is to see if the bot can receive an attachment with audio, then asynchronously transcribe those messages before responding.

Also you can try to use the “Speak” attribute of the Language Generation file, Maybe you can create a custom function with C# code for LG files.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/language-generation/20.extending-with-custom-functions